# including two tabs in tabsetpanel breaks shiny

Tags: r, shiny

ui.r

```
shinyUI(

  fluidPage(

    titlePanel("the title"),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Raw Data",verbatimTextOutput("theText")),
                    tabPanel("Raw Data2",verbatimTextOutput("theText"))
        )
      )
  )
)
```

server.r

```
library("shiny")
library("dplyr")
shinyServer(

function(input, output,session) {

  print("do it")
  output$theText <- renderText({
    return("please work")})
 }
)
```

If I remove one tabPanel it works, and "do it" is printed in the console and the title and "please work" is printed in the UI. Otherwise, with both, the UI with two tabs shows up and nothing is printed or displayed within the tabs, though an empty grey box does show up.

Using RStudio 0.99.332, R 3.1.2, shiny 0.11.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rshiny one output can go only to one place, which means that you have to create new output for other tabPanel.

```
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
     print("do it")
  output$theText <- renderText({
    return("please work")})
  output$theText2 <- renderText({
    return("please work")})
}

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("the title"),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Raw Data",verbatimTextOutput("theText")),
                    tabPanel("Raw Data2",verbatimTextOutput("theText2"))
        )
      )
  )

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: excellent. Seems strange that output can't be accessed twice like this, but there's probably a good reason behind the scenes. Thanks.
This is a perfect answer to demonstrate, but for anyone else looking at this, 
`placeholderText <- reactive({x<- longCalculationFunction();return(x)})` then
`output$theText1 <- renderText({placeholderText()})`
`output$theText2 <- renderText({placeholderText()})`
will work better for anything more intensive than returning a simple string